# Could the rest mass be somehow considered as a very exotic kind of kinetic energy?

Tags: spacetime, relativity, mass-energy

In its rest frame a free system of invariant mass $m$ has energy $E=mc^{2}$.

That frame is moving in spacetime with a four-velocity whose magnitude is $c$.

Inside my brain something asks:

Would there be a way to interpret $E$ as some sort of kinetic energy the system is getting from the motion of its frame in spacetime?

Comment: At a glance this almost makes sense, until you consider that the four-velocity of *all* objects is $c$, so all equal masses would have equal energies regardless of velocity and then you have to figure out what exactly kinetic energy is, then.

Comment: I doubt this is going to work, because you're trying to extract a non-Lorentz-invariant quantity (the energy, one of the components of the four-momentum) from a Lorentz-invariant one (the magnitude of the four-velocity).

Answer (score 0):

The rest mass of most stuff (but not all stuff) is very close to the sum of the rest masses of the neutrons and protons that make up the stuff. (And the mass of a system in general is different than the sum of the masses of the parts).

However the neutrons and protons themselves are made up of gluons (which have no mass) and quarks (which have relatively small masses).

So what you think of as rest mass (or rest energy) generally actually is other energy in the quarks and gluons, including kinetic energy.