# Can we see the rest-energy of a mass as its kinetic energy in the $ct$-direction?

Tags: energy, spacetime, inertial-frames, mass-energy

A mass $m$ at rest has an energy $E=mc^2$. Can we say this is its kinetic energy in the $ct$-direction?

Comment: Kind of, but see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/353236/123208 & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-momentum

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/243370/109928

Answer (score 1):

> A mass m at rest has an energy E=mc2. Can we say this is its kinetic energy in the ct-direction?

No, for a couple of reasons.

1. Kinetic energy is frame variant and mass is invariant. It doesn’t make to say an invariant quantity is a variant quantity.
2. The relativistic formula for KE is still 0 in that frame: $(\gamma-1) m c^2$.
3. The Newtonian formula for KE wouldn’t apply either, $\frac{1}{2} m c^2$, considering the velocity in the time direction to be $c $.

What can be said is that the mass is the magnitude of the momentum in spacetime (the four-momentum) in all frames.

Comment: But rest-energy is frame invariant, isn't it? Can't we say than that the rest energy is the kinetic energy through ct? Timelike particles move through time only when at rest, with the speed of light. But instead of 1/2mc^2 it becomes mc^2. Or is it potential energy? Somehow I tend to associate energy with motion.

Comment: According to E^2-p^2=m^2? As p=0, we can (?) say the energy is completely in the ct-direction. But as p increases, the energy in the t-direction gets less, and the energy in the space-direction increases. mc^2 is of course Lorentz invariant and doesn't give us the value of the kinetic energy through time for a moving particle, only for a particle at rest.

Comment: @IlGuercio I don't think that anything you mention changes my answer. In particular, point 3 makes the idea very problematic and does not go away with any amount of hand waving and word twisting.